# How to use appengine Datastore API's with Dataflow?

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-dataflow

We have a large dataset from an appengine app in our datastore. Now I want to do some ETL on them to push them to bigquery, and I thought of using a Dataflow batch job.

All examples I find are using this class to query the Datastore:

```
import com.google.api.services.datastore.DatastoreV1.Query;
```

And that does work. However, I'm not familiar wit this DatastoreV1 API and would like to use the API provided with the appengine SDK, like this:

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query;
```

The problem is that the DatastoreIO doesn't accept these queries:

```
PCollection<Entity> projects = p.apply(Read.from(DatastoreIO.source().withQuery(q).withDataset(DATASET_ID)));
```

It will only take DatastoreV1.Query objects. Is there any way to use the app engine provided API's? I'm much more familiar with those calls. Better yet, if we could use [Objectify](https://github.com/objectify/objectify), that would be awesome :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible with the current implementation of the API.  We can look at adding as a feature, and would gladly accept a pull request to expand the current functionality.  The AppEngine team is also actively working on increasing interoperability between their SDK and the Datastore API.

Comment: thanks Sam! Still getting familiar with the Dataflow SDK. Once I feel confident I'll look into a pull request!

Comment: Hey Sam, is there any update on the GAE team and their SDK integration?